# How would you save a list response from retrofit

Tags: java, android, call, retrofit2

Im using retrofit to get some information. Id like to store that information in a local variable so that if the user decides to favourite the item, i can just save it locally on the device.

```
public void fetchTrailerData(int movieId) {
    ApiInterface apiServies = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<TrailerResponse> call = apiServies.getTrailersForMovie(movieId, BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<TrailerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TrailerResponse> call, Response<TrailerResponse> response) {
            List<Trailer> trailers = response.body().getResults();
            if (trailers != null && trailers.size() > 0 && !trailers.isEmpty()) {
                Utilities util = new Utilities(mContext);
                util.populateTrailer(mView, trailers);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TrailerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as i searched for a solution and came up short.

Comment: Why can't you make use of sharedpreferences to hold the objects.

Comment: I never thought of that... :/ 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use local variables. Once execution flow goes out of the `onResponse` method, local variables will be cleaned.
Instead, use instance variables and assign returned results to them.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/yehe01/95c57bc0ec0c0366483738e4c26c9238) is a gist example of doing this.